# Graph Drawings (The graph not being regular is throwing me off)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

A graph $G$ with $ \chi(G) = 3$ and $G$ is not regular.

I am attempting to draw a graph with chromatic number $3$, that is irregular, would a Peterson graph apply to this situation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am attempting to draw a graph with chromatic number 3, that is irregular, would a Peterson graph apply to this situation

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Can you draw a graph with $\chi(G) = 3$? Can you draw a graph that is not regular? Can you draw them on the same piece of paper?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why this question is considered unclear. A regular graph is a graph  where each vertex has the same degree. By extension an irregular graph has at least two different degree values. All vertices in the peterson graph has degree three, and has chromatic number 3. This would not be an example of a irregular graph. I would recommend creating a graph with chromatic number 3 then if it is regular try adding extra vertices and connecting them to the graph in way that will produce different degrees.
If you have any questions about terminology ask in the comments of this answer.

If you tried my recommendation and you are still stuck here is a starting graph that has chromatic number 3 that is regular that you can vertices to:

> $k_3$ The 3-vertex complete graph

If you still can't do it even after doing some attempts here is a solution: (if you found a different solution from the one in the next spoiler, Great! There are many solutions it doesn't need to match mine.)

> $W_5$ The 5-vertex wheel graph. The central vertex has degree 4 and the rest have degree 3. It has chromatic number 3.